# Connect to Phoenix Hbase deployed as a docker image through SquirrelClient Remotely

Tags: docker, hbase, apache-phoenix, squirrel.windows

I've deployed Hbase(Standalone), Zookeeper and Phoenix as a docker image in a virtual host. The image started successfully without any issues. Also after some changes in the config file, I could connect to the Hbase using Phoenix by ./sqlline.py 127.0.0.1:2181:/hbase-unsecure in the docker image container. After successfully creating table and some sample queries tested, I tried to connect through Squirrel-Client from my windows machine which is throwing TimeOutException.

For Info, the required hbase*client.jar and Phoenix*jar has been copied to the squirrel Client.

Error in SqurrelClient app:
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.awaitConnection(OpenConnectionCommand.java:132)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.access$100(OpenConnectionCommand.java:45)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand$2.run(OpenConnectionCommand.java:115)
    at

Any help on how to connect to the Phoenix remotely would be appreciated.

Thank You!!

Comment: sounds like the ports are not open or forwarded?